# Discord.py | fetch_user(user_id) in slash commands being too long

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have tried creating an unban slash-command, to unban users in my discord Server. I got the slash command it self working, but when I am copy pasting the ID of a banned user in to the slash command it says: "Input a valid Integer". Which is just confusing, because python3 shouldn't have a max integer value. I tried making the ID shorter(deleting some numbers) and then after I deleted the first 3 numbers it didn't say "Input a valid Integer" anymore.

```py
bot.tree.command(name="unban")
async def unban(interaction: discord.Interaction, user_id: int=None, * , reason: str=None):
    if user_id is None:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="'user_id' missing!", description="Specify a user ID in order to unban that User.", color=0xff0000)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    elif reason is None:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="'reason' missing!", description=f"Specify a for what you want to unban {user_id.name} for.", color=0xff0000)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    else:
        try:
            user = await bot.fetch_user(user_id)
            ban_entry = await interaction.guild.fetch_ban(user)
            if ban_entry is None:
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{user.name} already is unbanned!", description="Please recheck if you have used the correct User ID.", color=0xff0000)
                await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
            else:
                await interaction.guild.unban(user)
                embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Unbanned {user.name}", description=f"{user.name} with the ID: {user_id}, has been unbanned because {reason}" , color=0xff0000)
                await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
        except discord.NotFound:
            embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{user_id} not found!", description="Please recheck if you have typed in the User ID correctly.", color=0xff0000)
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

What it says when I copy paste in the full ID.
[image: Error 1]

What it says after I delete the first 3 numbers.
[image: Error 2]

Showing that it doesn't work when I only delete 2 numbers.
[image: Error 3]

For now I didn't try anything yet, since I'm pretty new to coding and wouldn't now where else I could be asking for help.

Comment: This is a common bug with discord, I solved this by passing the id as a ```string``` and the converting it as an ```int``` with ```user_id = int(user_id)```.

Comment: @atomfrog how exactly would I do that? Sorry for asking but I am fairly new to python and coding in generell.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make the argument a `str` and then convert it back to an `int` in a later state of the code.

**How it could work:**

```py
async def unban(interaction: discord.Interaction, user_id: str, * , reason: str):

# Your other code

user = await bot.fetch_user(int(user_id)) # Convert it back to an integer

# Rest of the code
```

Please note that I also removed `=None` from `user_id` and `reason` which makes them a required argument now. This way, you can save yourself some lines of code as you returned errors when one of the earlier optional arguments wasn't given.

Comment: Thank you, but the other guy already helped me out. Thanks a lot though.